# How to register Office Web Add-in in the Microsoft App Registration Portal

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, outlook-addin, office-addins

[image]I am reading [Microsoft's documentation on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2), that is inscrutable as usual, and following step by step I am not sure how to fill half the fields there:

I add two platforms Web and Web API

### Web

for Redirect URL I add the Project URL found under properties of my Visual Studio Office Add-in? Is that correct?

### Web API

for application URI I add the same value? Also what does this mean:

> The fully qualified domain name (except for protocol) of the add-in. You must use a domain that you own. For this reason, you cannot use certain well-known domains such as azurewebsites.net or cloudapp.net

What if my Add-in, which is basically a website is hosted on Azure? Why can't I use azurewebsites.net?

What exactly should I put in Application ID and where to retrieve it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for Redirect URL I add the Project URL found under properties of my
>   Visual Studio Office Add-in? Is that correct?

That's correct. The Redirect URI is the Project URL. You can also copy the SSL URL and add this URL to the list of Redirect URLs in the Registration Portal’s list of Redirect URLs:

[image]

> for application URI I add the same value?

No. As the documentation said that,

> An Application ID URI has been generated of the form “api://$App ID
>   GUID$”.

**Application ID URI example:**

This means that if you do not input any value in the Application ID URI, it will be generated by default as `api://<applicaitonID>`,just like.If you want to define your own Application ID URI, you can configure it like `api://<yourdomain>/<applicaitonID>`.

it can be like `api://c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b`,
`api://localhost:6789/c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b7` or `api://example.azurewebsites.net/c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b7`

**Scope Value example:**

The application ID URI be used with scope. The scope value you should use in your `web.config`or `app.config` should be `<applicationID URI>/<scope>`. If you don't input any value in the Application ID URI, the scope value should be `api://<Application Id>/<Scope Name>`.

the scope value can be like:`api://c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b7/access_as_user` ,`api://localhost:6789/c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b7/access_as_user` or `api://example.azurewebsites.net/c6c1f32b-5e55-4997-881a-753cc1d563b7/access_as_user`

Comment: Ok, but what about the Application ID in the section "Pre-authorized applications". Where do i get that from?

Comment: @nmrlqa4 . That is  the feature which indicate the client applicaitons that your web App trusts.  you can  sepecify a client app here which can call  your web api with no consent UI.

Comment: So in that case should I enter the ID value taken from the manifest of my Outlook Web Add-In in Visual Studio? Problem is when I enter that value it gives me an error "Application ID provided in pre-authorized applications cannot be found", yet entering the ones provided in the microsoft documentation works fine?!?!

Comment: For this case, I don't think you need to enter Applicaiton ID in the  "Pre-authorized applications". You can follow [the document you post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/register-sso-add-in-aad-v2) to register your app.

Comment: My pleasure.:-)